# Multiple onActivityResult{} in same class?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm doing a few dialogs pickers on my app and using a switch-case on my `onClickListener` but dialogs are calling for a `onActivityResult{}` but app is crashing if I add 2... Can I put them both in the same `onActivityResult{}` calling each by results codes? Code below:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(arg0.getId()){
            case R.id.bContacts:

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); 
                        startActivityForResult(i, PICK_CONTACT); 

                break;  

            case R.id.bRingtone:

                String uri = null;
                Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
                intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select ringtone for notifications:");
                intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
                intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
                intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                startActivityForResult( intent, Set_Ringtone);

                break;
        }
    }

 @Override 
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
    data) 
        { 
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
            Cursor c = getContact(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);

            if (c.moveToNext()) {
                String name = c
                        .getString(c
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                callName.setText(name);
                String phoneNumber = c
                        .getString(c
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                callNum.setText(phoneNumber);
                Log.d("Cont", "name "+name+" no. " + phoneNumber);
            } 
        } 


  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent intent)
    {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 5)
        {
             Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);

             if (uri != null)
             {

                 String ringTonePath = uri.toString();
                 Toast.makeText(this, "GOT IT" + ringTonePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
             else
             {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "DIDNT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         }            
     }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can handle both intents in the same `onActivityResult()` method. That's why you send a request code with your intent when you call `startActivityForResult()`, you get it back when the result comes in to differentiate. Your method could look like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{ 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 

    switch(requestCode) {
        case PICK_CONTACT:
           // handle the contact result
        break;

        case Set_Ringtone:
           // handle the ringtone result
        break;
    }
}
```

Your app most likely crashes because you try to work with details of the result that are not provided if you select the wrong intent *(e.g. you try to read a contact name here, a ringtone result will not work with that)*.

Comment: That's it. My switch case didn't work before... because my intents on the 2 OnActivityReuslts were diff:

protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent intent)

protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data)

So when SET_RINGTONE was being called intent wasn't resolved.

YOu're answer helped me see the light!